# Variable value is not recognized after using gnu parallel?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, gnu-parallel

I have a below shell script from which I am trying to copy 5 files in parallel. I am running my below shell script on `machineA` which tries to copy the  file from machineB and machineC.

If the file is not there in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC` for sure.

I am using GNU Parallel here to download five files in parallel.

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly PRIMARY=/tech01/primary
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(550 274 2 546 278 6 558 282 10 554 286 14) # this will have more file numbers

dir1=/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501

find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_copy() {
  el=$1
  scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
}
export -f do_copy
parallel -j 5 do_copy ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

**Problem Statement:-**

The problem I am facing with the above script is - It is not able to recognize `${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}`, `${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}`, `$dir1` and `$PRIMARY` inside `do_copy` method? And I am not sure why?

If I try to print out like this inside `do_copy` method nothing is printed out?

```
  echo ${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}    
  echo ${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}
```

But if I print out same thing just above `do_copy` method, then it works fine?

Anything I am missing here?

**Update:-**

Below is the code I am using -

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/tech01/primary
export FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
export MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(0 548 272 4 544 276 8 556 280)

export dir1=/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501

find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_copy() {
  el=$1
  scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
}
export -f do_copy
parallel -j 8 do_copy ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

**Another Update:-**

This is what I got after running the below script -

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/tech01/primary
export FILERS_LOCATION=(slc4b03c-407d.stratus.slc.ebay.com chd1b02c-0db8.stratus.phx.ebay.com)
export MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(0 548 272 4 544)

export dir1=/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501

find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

 echo ${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}    
 echo ${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}

do_copy() {
  el=$1
  echo "scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 bullseye@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 bullseye@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/."
}
export -f do_copy
parallel -j 3 do_copy ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

Output I got -

```
david@tvxdbx1143:/home/david$ ./scp_files5.sh
machineB
machineC
When using programs that use GNU Parallel to process data for publication please cite:

  O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool,
  ;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.

This helps funding further development; and it won't cost you a cent.

To silence this citation notice run 'parallel --bibtex' once or use '--no-notice'.

scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_0_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_0_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/.
scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_548_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_548_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/.
scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_272_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_272_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/.
scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_4_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_4_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/.
scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_544_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@:/techbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501/t1_weekly_1680_544_200003_5.data /tech01/primary/.
```

Comment: Your edited version works for me. Please do: echo $SHELL

Comment: `/bin/bash` this is what I got.

Comment: Prepend scp with 'echo' and see if you get the correct output.

Comment: Do the examples in the tutorial work?

Comment: @OleTange: I have updated the question with the scp output. It is not even making correct scp output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exporting them and removing the array as [bash can not export arrays](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg01774.html):

```
export PRIMARY=/data01/primary
export FILERS_LOCATION_1=machineB
export FILERS_LOCATION_2=machineC
export MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot

export dir1=/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501
```

Or simply put all the constant variables into the function:

```
#!/bin/bash

PRIMARY_PARTITION=(0 548 272 4 544 276 8 556 280)

PRIMARY=/data01/primary
find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_copy() {
  el=$1

  PRIMARY=/data01/primary
  FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
  MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot

  dir1=/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140501

  scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
}
export -f do_copy
parallel -j 8 do_copy ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

Depending on what kinds of files you are copying you should look into `rsync -z`
 instead of `scp`. And consider running `parallel --bibtex` once (as suggested by parallel).

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work somehow? I have updated the question with the shell script details. May be I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Apparently [bash arrays can not be exported](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg01774.html). Use FILERS_LOCATION_1 and FILERS_LOCATION_2 instead.

Comment: Actually Ole said that code worked for him. What versions of bash do you both have? `bash --version`

Comment: @mtm bash version I have is `GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: It seems you need bash 4.3 to export arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script Follow mtm's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have exported a function but not the variables you are trying to use directly in the function.

`parallel` will launch a new shell for each run of `do_copy` and in that shell the variables are interpreted and do not exist.

If the `-s SERVER` option is used the `--env VAR` option will copy `VAR` from the initial `parallel` shell to the remote environment the command is run in:

```
parallel -j 5 -S localhost --env do_copy --env PRIMARY --env FILERS_LOCATION do_copy ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

You may be able to get away with the above localhost hack as I can't see a simple way to implement your multiple server logic into the parallel server `-S` options (unless you are guaranteed one server won't have the file?)

The nicer way would be to export the variables as Ole suggested, or passing all the require values as parameters to the `do_copy` function

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried running like this and still it doesn't work? `parallel -j 5 --env PRIMARY --env FILERS_LOCATION --env dir1 do_copy ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"` Anything wrong?

Comment: --env is only for remote runnning.

Comment: @OleTange: I see, and I tried your suggestion as well. Am I doing something wrong as well?

Comment: aahh forgot about that, noted. cheers

Comment: @mtm: I also tried Ole suggestion but that is also not working for me. I have updated the question as well. Can you take a look?